# How can I create a textbox with a solid background and a wavy seam at the top?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to create an animated GIF inforgraphic in LaTeX. For that I want to arrange text boxes in a three column layout in row boxes of various colors that are separated by a wavy line (ideally a sinusoid). I have an idea about how to draw a single one of these separator lines with `tikz`, however the background of each box would have to have a matching seam at the top and it seems that this would require a `\foreach` within a `\fill` command, and that seems to be impossible syntactically. Is `tikz` the right tool for this? I don't want to draw it with several adjacent filled shapes because that could possibly cause flashing when viewed in some PDF viewers (I also want to create a PDF version of it). There are about 12 such boxes in various colors and heights, so it would be convenient if that was automated.

[image: Mock-up]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[default,regular]{raleway}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[paperwidth=29.7cm,paperheight=50cm,margin=0cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\lineskiplimit}{2pt}
\setlength{\lineskip}{2pt}

\pagecolor{white}
\definecolor{mygrey}{rgb}{0.6,0.6,0.6}
\definecolor{myurl}{HTML}{5687D1}
\definecolor{myboxbluel}{HTML}{DFF0FD}
\definecolor{myboxblued}{HTML}{6DBAEC}

\newsavebox{\MyMinBackBox}
\newenvironment{myminipage}[0]{%
  \begin{lrbox}{\MyMinBackBox}%
    \begin{minipage}{29.7cm}%
    }{%
    \end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]%
      \fill[fill=myboxbluel] (0,-\dimexpr\ht\MyMinBackBox\relax) -- (29.7,-\dimexpr\ht\MyMinBackBox\relax) -- (29.7,0) -- (0,0);
      \draw[draw=myboxblued,thick] (29.7,0) -- (0,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \llap{\usebox{\MyMinBackBox}}%
}

\begin{document}
\foreach \n in {0,...,4}{%
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \begin{textblock}{10.5}(0.65,0.65)%
    Box top left
  \end{textblock}%
  \begin{textblock}{17.1}(11.8,1.1)%
     Box top right
  \end{textblock}%
  \null%
  \vspace{2.4cm}%
  \begin{myminipage}%
    \begin{multicols}{3}
      \lipsum[1]
      \columnbreak
      \lipsum[2]
      \columnbreak
      \lipsum[3]
    \end{multicols}
  \end{myminipage}%
  \newpage
}
\end{document}
```

This is roughly the output produced by the code above. The height height of the background is only half the size it should be for some reason. I've also trouble adding some padding to the three-column container `minipage`, but that's perhaps worth a separate question.

[image: Current result.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the whole thing in TikZ:

[image]

The code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,fit,backgrounds,decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[default,regular]{raleway}
\usepackage[paperwidth=32cm,paperheight=50cm,margin=1cm]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\pagecolor{white}
\definecolor{mygrey}{rgb}{0.6,0.6,0.6}
\definecolor{myurl}{HTML}{5687D1}
\definecolor{myboxbluel}{HTML}{DFF0FD}
\definecolor{myboxblued}{HTML}{6DBAEC}

\newsavebox{\MyMinBackBox}
\newcommand\myminipage[2][]{\node[text width=9.3cm,inner sep=0pt,#1] {#2};}

\tikzset{
  myborder/.style={
  decorate,decoration={snake},
  }
}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{6cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\myminipage[name=box11,anchor=west]{\lipsum[1]}
\myminipage[name=box12,right=of box11.north east,anchor=north west]{\lipsum[2]}
\myminipage[name=box13,right=of box12.north east ,anchor=north west]{\lipsum[3]}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\node[
  inner xsep=0pt,
  inner ysep=25pt,
  fit={(box11.north west) (box11.south west) (box13.south east)}
  ] (bgupper) {};
\begin{scope}
\clip[myborder]
  ([shift={(-2cm,-10pt)}]bgupper.north west) -- 
  ([shift={(2cm,-10pt)}]bgupper.north east) -- 
  ([shift={(2cm,-2cm)}]bgupper.south east) -- 
  ([shift={(-2cm,-2cm)}]bgupper.south west) -- cycle 
  ; 
\fill[blue!20]
  ([xshift=-10pt]bgupper.north west) rectangle ([xshift=10pt]bgupper.south east); 
\end{scope}
\end{pgfonlayer}

\myminipage[name=box21,below=5pt of bgupper.south west,anchor=north west]{\lipsum[4]}
\myminipage[name=box22,right=of box21.north east,anchor=north west]{\lipsum[2]}
\myminipage[name=box23,right=of box22.north east ,anchor=north west]{\lipsum[1]}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\node[
  inner xsep=0pt,
  inner ysep=25pt,
  fit={(box21.north west) (box21.south west) (box23.south east)}
  ] (bgmiddle) {};
\begin{scope}
\clip[myborder]
  ([shift={(-2cm,-10pt)}]bgmiddle.north west) -- 
  ([shift={(2cm,-10pt)}]bgmiddle.north east) -- 
  ([shift={(2cm,-2cm)}]bgmiddle.south east) -- 
  ([shift={(-2cm,-2cm)}]bgmiddle.south west) -- cycle 
  ; 
\fill[yellow!20]
  ([xshift=-10pt]bgmiddle.north west) rectangle ([xshift=10pt]bgmiddle.south east); 
\end{scope}
\end{pgfonlayer}

\myminipage[name=box31,below=15pt of bgmiddle.south west,anchor=north west]{\lipsum[4]}
\myminipage[name=box32,right=of box31.north east,anchor=north west]{\lipsum[2]}
\myminipage[name=box33,right=of box32.north east ,anchor=north west]{\lipsum[1]}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\node[
  inner xsep=0pt,
  inner ysep=25pt,
  fit={(box31.north west) (box31.south west) (box33.south east)}
  ] (bglower) {};
\begin{scope}
\clip[myborder]
  ([shift={(-2cm,-10pt)}]bglower.north west) -- 
  ([shift={(2cm,-10pt)}]bglower.north east) -- 
  ([shift={(2cm,15pt)}]bglower.south east) -- 
  ([shift={(-2cm,15pt)}]bglower.south west) -- cycle 
  ; 
\fill[red!20]
  ([xshift=-10pt]bglower.north west) rectangle ([xshift=10pt]bglower.south east); 
\end{scope}
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The filling is done in the `background` layer; the wavy border is produced using clipping and a `snake` decoration.